# Class that has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to add a controller which keeps giving me and error whereby it says unable to retrieve metadata. One or more validation error were detected during model generation. And something about no keys defined.

This is my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace User_Management.Models
{
    public class UserDB
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public string Security { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserDB> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDBs] (
    [EmployeeId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]   NCHAR (15)     NULL,
    [Email]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [FullName]   NCHAR (20)     NULL,
    [Password]   NCHAR (15)     NOT NULL,
    [JoinDate]   DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Position]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Team]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Security]   NVARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL,
    [Status]     INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserDBs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeId] ASC)
);
```

Im still stuck trying to add a controller for this...

Comment: Please post actual error message and code mentioned in error's call stack.

Comment: erm here
[Error Image](http://s2.postimg.org/wtwp2hgah/Capture.png)

Comment: It is better to copy text from the error (Ctrl+C) and update your post with the error. (Also no I see that I have no idea about your problem, but someone else may)... Side note: consider using proper asp.net-mvc tag instead of generic MVC one for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
[Key]
public int Id(or UserId) in UserDB class
```

Comment: You probably meant `EmployeeId`, not `Id`

Comment: tried already still no luck =(

Comment: Nevermind i got it to work by adding a space in between each public  ....